# Failed to update parameters. Database Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#

I have created an application to manage the cutting parameters on a Laser machine. In the application form, there is a button to save the changes made by the user in the parameter values.
When the `Save Parameter` button is clicked, the EventHandler should compare each value in the form to the subsequent value of it it in the Database.
If there is a difference in the values, it should construct an SQL Statement to update that specific parameter and the new value to update it in the Database.
But I keep getting the error

> Failed to update parameters. Database Error: Data type mismatch in
> criteria expression.

Below you may find the EventHandler I created

```
private void SaveParametersButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(AppConfigToolManager.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM CuttingParameters WHERE Material = @Material AND Thickness = @Thickness AND Gas = @Gas AND PiercingType = @PiercingType";

            using (OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection))
            {
                        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", selectedMaterial);
                        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", selectedThickness);
                        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gas", selectedGas);
                        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PiercingType", selectedPiercingType);

                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Dictionary<string, object> updatedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                void CompareAndSaveParameter(string paraName, TextBox textBox, object dbValue)
                                {
                                    string logMessage = $"Comparing {paraName}: FormValue = {textBox.Text}, DBValue = {dbValue}";

                                    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
                                    logger.Log(logMessage);

                                    bool valuesEqual = false;
                                    string dataType = dbValue.GetType().ToString();                                    
                                    if (textBox.Text == null && dbValue == null)
                                    {
                                        valuesEqual = true;
                                    }
                                    else if (textBox.Text != null && dbValue != null)
                                    {                                        
                                        if (dbValue is double && double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out double doubleValue))
                                        {
                                            valuesEqual = (double)dbValue == doubleValue;
                                        }
                                        else if (dbValue is int && int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out int intValue))
                                        {
                                            valuesEqual = (int)dbValue == intValue;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {                                                
                                                object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, dbValue.GetType());
                                                valuesEqual = object.Equals(convertedValue, dbValue);
                                            }
                                            catch (InvalidCastException)
                                            {                                                
                                                valuesEqual = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    string valuesEqualMessage = $"ValuesEqual: {valuesEqual}, DataType: {dataType}";
                                    Console.WriteLine(valuesEqualMessage);
                                    logger.Log(valuesEqualMessage);

                                    if (!valuesEqual)
                                    {
                                        if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out double doubleValue))
                                        {
                                            updatedValues[paraName.Substring(1)] = doubleValue;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            updatedValues[paraName.Substring(1)] = textBox.Text;
                                        }

                                        string addedToUpdatedValuesMessage = $"Added to updatedValues: {paraName.Substring(1)}";
                                        Console.WriteLine(addedToUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                        logger.Log(addedToUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                    }
                                    else if (updatedValues.ContainsKey(paraName.Substring(1)))
                                    {
                                        updatedValues.Remove(paraName.Substring(1));
                                        string removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage = $"Removed from updatedValues: {paraName.Substring(1)}";
                                        Console.WriteLine(removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                        logger.Log(removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                    }
                                }

                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1CuttingSpeed", Cut1CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut1CuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1GasPressure", Cut1GasPressure, reader["Cut1GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1Frequency", Cut1Frequency, reader["Cut1Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1NozzleHeight", Cut1NozzleHeight, reader["Cut1NozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1PowerMin", Cut1PowerMin, reader["Cut1PowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1PowerMax", Cut1PowerMax, reader["Cut1PowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1DutyCycle", Cut1DutyCycle, reader["Cut1DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1FocusHeight", Cut1FocusHeight, reader["Cut1FocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1LeadInFeed", Cut1LeadInFeed, reader["Cut1LeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1Compensation", Cut1Compensation, reader["Cut1Compensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2CuttingSpeed", Cut2CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut2CuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2GasPressure", Cut2GasPressure, reader["Cut2GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2Frequency", Cut2Frequency, reader["Cut2Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2NozzleHeight", Cut2NozzleHeight, reader["Cut2NozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2PowerMin", Cut2PowerMin, reader["Cut2PowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2PowerMax", Cut2PowerMax, reader["Cut2PowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2DutyCycle", Cut2DutyCycle, reader["Cut2DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2FocusHeight", Cut2FocusHeight, reader["Cut2FocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2LeadInFeed", Cut2LeadInFeed, reader["Cut2LeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2Compensation", Cut2Compensation, reader["Cut2Compensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3CuttingSpeed", Cut3CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut3CuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3GasPressure", Cut3GasPressure, reader["Cut3GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3Frequency", Cut3Frequency, reader["Cut3Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3NozzleHeight", Cut3NozzleHeight, reader["Cut3NozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3PowerMin", Cut3PowerMin, reader["Cut3PowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3PowerMax", Cut3PowerMax, reader["Cut3PowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3DutyCycle", Cut3DutyCycle, reader["Cut3DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3FocusHeight", Cut3FocusHeight, reader["Cut3FocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3LeadInFeed", Cut3LeadInFeed, reader["Cut3LeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3Compensation", Cut3Compensation, reader["Cut3Compensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleCuttingSpeed", SmallHoleCuttingSpeed, reader["SmallHoleCuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleGasPressure", SmallHoleGasPressure, reader["SmallHoleGasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleFrequency", SmallHoleFrequency, reader["SmallHoleFrequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleNozzleHeight", SmallHoleNozzleHeight, reader["SmallHoleNozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHolePowerMin", SmallHolePowerMin, reader["SmallHolePowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHolePowerMax", SmallHolePowerMax, reader["SmallHolePowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleDutyCycle", SmallHoleDutyCycle, reader["SmallHoleDutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleFocusHeight", SmallHoleFocusHeight, reader["SmallHoleFocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleLeadInFeed", SmallHoleLeadInFeed, reader["SmallHoleLeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleCompensation", SmallHoleCompensation, reader["SmallHoleCompensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningCuttingSpeed", FilmBurningCuttingSpeed, reader["FilmBurningCuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningGasPressure", FilmBurningGasPressure, reader["FilmBurningGasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningFrequency", FilmBurningFrequency, reader["FilmBurningFrequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningNozzleHeight", FilmBurningNozzleHeight, reader["FilmBurningNozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningPowerMin", FilmBurningPowerMin, reader["FilmBurningPowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningPowerMax", FilmBurningPowerMax, reader["FilmBurningPowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningDutyCycle", FilmBurningDutyCycle, reader["FilmBurningDutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningFocusHeight", FilmBurningFocusHeight, reader["FilmBurningFocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningLeadInFeed", FilmBurningLeadInFeed, reader["FilmBurningLeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningCompensation", FilmBurningCompensation, reader["FilmBurningCompensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingCuttingSpeed", MarkingCuttingSpeed, reader["MarkingCuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingGasPressure", MarkingGasPressure, reader["MarkingGasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingFrequency", MarkingFrequency, reader["MarkingFrequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingNozzleHeight", MarkingNozzleHeight, reader["MarkingNozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingPowerMin", MarkingPowerMin, reader["MarkingPowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingPowerMax", MarkingPowerMax, reader["MarkingPowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingDutyCycle", MarkingDutyCycle, reader["MarkingDutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingFocusHeight", MarkingFocusHeight, reader["MarkingFocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingLeadInFeed", MarkingLeadInFeed, reader["MarkingLeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingCompensation", MarkingCompensation, reader["MarkingCompensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolCuttingSpeed", PathCoolCuttingSpeed, reader["PathCoolCuttingSpeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolGasPressure", PathCoolGasPressure, reader["PathCoolGasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolFrequency", PathCoolFrequency, reader["PathCoolFrequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolNozzleHeight", PathCoolNozzleHeight, reader["PathCoolNozzleHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolPowerMin", PathCoolPowerMin, reader["PathCoolPowerMin"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolPowerMax", PathCoolPowerMax, reader["PathCoolPowerMax"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolDutyCycle", PathCoolDutyCycle, reader["PathCoolDutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolFocusHeight", PathCoolFocusHeight, reader["PathCoolFocusHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolLeadInFeed", PathCoolLeadInFeed, reader["PathCoolLeadInFeed"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolCompensation", PathCoolCompensation, reader["PathCoolCompensation"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Power", PiercingStage1Power, reader["PiercingStage1Power"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Frequency", PiercingStage1Frequency, reader["PiercingStage1Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1DutyCycle", PiercingStage1DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage1DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1PierceHeight", PiercingStage1PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage1PierceHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Focus", PiercingStage1Focus, reader["PiercingStage1Focus"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1GasPressure", PiercingStage1GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage1GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1PierceTime", PiercingStage1PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage1PierceTime"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Power", PiercingStage2Power, reader["PiercingStage2Power"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Frequency", PiercingStage2Frequency, reader["PiercingStage2Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2DutyCycle", PiercingStage2DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage2DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2PierceHeight", PiercingStage2PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage2PierceHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Focus", PiercingStage2Focus, reader["PiercingStage2Focus"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2GasPressure", PiercingStage2GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage2GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2PierceTime", PiercingStage2PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage2PierceTime"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Power", PiercingStage3Power, reader["PiercingStage3Power"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Frequency", PiercingStage3Frequency, reader["PiercingStage3Frequency"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3DutyCycle", PiercingStage3DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage3DutyCycle"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3PierceHeight", PiercingStage3PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage3PierceHeight"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Focus", PiercingStage3Focus, reader["PiercingStage3Focus"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3GasPressure", PiercingStage3GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage3GasPressure"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3PierceTime", PiercingStage3PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage3PierceTime"]);
                                CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay"]);

                                if (updatedValues.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("No changes found to be updated.");
                                    return;
                                }

                                string updateQuery = "UPDATE CuttingParameters SET " +
                                    string.Join(", ", updatedValues.Select(kv => $"[{kv.Key}] = ?")) +
                                    " WHERE Material = ? AND Thickness = ? AND Gas = ? AND PiercingType = ?";

                                Console.WriteLine("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);

                                foreach (var kvp in updatedValues)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
                                    logger.Log("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);
                                    logger.Log($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, connection))
                                    {
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", selectedMaterial);
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", selectedThickness);
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gas", selectedGas);
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PiercingType", selectedPiercingType);

                                        foreach (var kvp in updatedValues)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
                                            logger.Log("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);
                                            logger.Log($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");

                                    OleDbParameter parameter;
                                    if (double.TryParse(kvp.Value.ToString(), out double doubleValue))
                                    {
                                        parameter = new OleDbParameter($"@{kvp.Key}", OleDbType.Double);
                                        parameter.Value = doubleValue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        parameter = new OleDbParameter($"@{kvp.Key}", OleDbType.VarChar);
                                        parameter.Value = kvp.Value;
                                    }
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                                }

                                int rowsAffected = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Parameters updated successfully.");
                                    logger.Log("Parameters updated successfully.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("No rows were updated. No changes found to be updated.");
                                    logger.Log("No rows were updated. No changes found to be updated.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (OleDbException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.Message);
                            logger.Log("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.Message);
                            logger.LogError("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.Message);
                            logger.Log("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.Message);
                            logger.LogError("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.Message);
        logger.Log("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.Message);
        logger.LogError("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure where and how, but remember that AddWithValue can build the parameters of the correct type only looking at the type of the value. If a value has the wrong type the db engine could give you this error.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the issue. the problem was the data type being used. there was a slight problem as the datatype had to to be converted to string when displaying in the textbox from double and then back to double when writing back to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. the problem was the data type being used. there was a slight problem as the datatype had to to be converted to string when displaying in the textbox from double and then back to double when writing back to the db.
Here is the code

private void SaveParametersButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(AppConfigToolManager.ConnectionString))
{
connection.Open();

```
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM CuttingParameters WHERE Material = @Material AND Thickness = @Thickness AND Gas = @Gas AND PiercingType = @PiercingType";

                using (OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection))
                {
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", selectedMaterial);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", selectedThickness);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gas", selectedGas);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PiercingType", selectedPiercingType);

                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, object> updatedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                            void CompareAndSaveParameter(string paraName, TextBox textBox, object dbValue)
                            {
                                string logMessage = $"Comparing {paraName}: FormValue = {textBox.Text}, DBValue = {dbValue}";

                                Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
                                logger.Log(logMessage);

                                bool valuesEqual = false;
                                string dataType = dbValue.GetType().ToString();                                    
                                if (textBox.Text == null && dbValue == null)
                                {
                                    valuesEqual = true;
                                }
                                else if (textBox.Text != null && dbValue != null)
                                {                                        
                                    if (dbValue is double && double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out double doubleValue))
                                    {
                                        valuesEqual = (double)dbValue == doubleValue;
                                    }
                                    else if (dbValue is int && int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out int intValue))
                                    {
                                        valuesEqual = (int)dbValue == intValue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {                                                
                                            object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, dbValue.GetType());
                                            valuesEqual = object.Equals(convertedValue, dbValue);
                                        }
                                        catch (InvalidCastException)
                                        {                                                
                                            valuesEqual = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                string valuesEqualMessage = $"ValuesEqual: {valuesEqual}, DataType: {dataType}";
                                Console.WriteLine(valuesEqualMessage);
                                logger.Log(valuesEqualMessage);

                                if (!valuesEqual)
                                {
                                    if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out double doubleValue))
                                    {
                                        updatedValues[paraName.Substring(1)] = doubleValue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        updatedValues[paraName.Substring(1)] = textBox.Text;
                                    }

                                    string addedToUpdatedValuesMessage = $"Added to updatedValues: {paraName.Substring(1)}";
                                    Console.WriteLine(addedToUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                    logger.Log(addedToUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                }
                                else if (updatedValues.ContainsKey(paraName.Substring(1)))
                                {
                                    updatedValues.Remove(paraName.Substring(1));
                                    string removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage = $"Removed from updatedValues: {paraName.Substring(1)}";
                                    Console.WriteLine(removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                    logger.Log(removedFromUpdatedValuesMessage);
                                }
                            }

                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1CuttingSpeed", Cut1CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut1CuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1GasPressure", Cut1GasPressure, reader["Cut1GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1Frequency", Cut1Frequency, reader["Cut1Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1NozzleHeight", Cut1NozzleHeight, reader["Cut1NozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1PowerMin", Cut1PowerMin, reader["Cut1PowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1PowerMax", Cut1PowerMax, reader["Cut1PowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1DutyCycle", Cut1DutyCycle, reader["Cut1DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1FocusHeight", Cut1FocusHeight, reader["Cut1FocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1LeadInFeed", Cut1LeadInFeed, reader["Cut1LeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut1Compensation", Cut1Compensation, reader["Cut1Compensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2CuttingSpeed", Cut2CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut2CuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2GasPressure", Cut2GasPressure, reader["Cut2GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2Frequency", Cut2Frequency, reader["Cut2Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2NozzleHeight", Cut2NozzleHeight, reader["Cut2NozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2PowerMin", Cut2PowerMin, reader["Cut2PowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2PowerMax", Cut2PowerMax, reader["Cut2PowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2DutyCycle", Cut2DutyCycle, reader["Cut2DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2FocusHeight", Cut2FocusHeight, reader["Cut2FocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2LeadInFeed", Cut2LeadInFeed, reader["Cut2LeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut2Compensation", Cut2Compensation, reader["Cut2Compensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3CuttingSpeed", Cut3CuttingSpeed, reader["Cut3CuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3GasPressure", Cut3GasPressure, reader["Cut3GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3Frequency", Cut3Frequency, reader["Cut3Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3NozzleHeight", Cut3NozzleHeight, reader["Cut3NozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3PowerMin", Cut3PowerMin, reader["Cut3PowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3PowerMax", Cut3PowerMax, reader["Cut3PowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3DutyCycle", Cut3DutyCycle, reader["Cut3DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3FocusHeight", Cut3FocusHeight, reader["Cut3FocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3LeadInFeed", Cut3LeadInFeed, reader["Cut3LeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@Cut3Compensation", Cut3Compensation, reader["Cut3Compensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleCuttingSpeed", SmallHoleCuttingSpeed, reader["SmallHoleCuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleGasPressure", SmallHoleGasPressure, reader["SmallHoleGasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleFrequency", SmallHoleFrequency, reader["SmallHoleFrequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleNozzleHeight", SmallHoleNozzleHeight, reader["SmallHoleNozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHolePowerMin", SmallHolePowerMin, reader["SmallHolePowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHolePowerMax", SmallHolePowerMax, reader["SmallHolePowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleDutyCycle", SmallHoleDutyCycle, reader["SmallHoleDutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleFocusHeight", SmallHoleFocusHeight, reader["SmallHoleFocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleLeadInFeed", SmallHoleLeadInFeed, reader["SmallHoleLeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@SmallHoleCompensation", SmallHoleCompensation, reader["SmallHoleCompensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningCuttingSpeed", FilmBurningCuttingSpeed, reader["FilmBurningCuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningGasPressure", FilmBurningGasPressure, reader["FilmBurningGasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningFrequency", FilmBurningFrequency, reader["FilmBurningFrequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningNozzleHeight", FilmBurningNozzleHeight, reader["FilmBurningNozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningPowerMin", FilmBurningPowerMin, reader["FilmBurningPowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningPowerMax", FilmBurningPowerMax, reader["FilmBurningPowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningDutyCycle", FilmBurningDutyCycle, reader["FilmBurningDutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningFocusHeight", FilmBurningFocusHeight, reader["FilmBurningFocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningLeadInFeed", FilmBurningLeadInFeed, reader["FilmBurningLeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@FilmBurningCompensation", FilmBurningCompensation, reader["FilmBurningCompensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingCuttingSpeed", MarkingCuttingSpeed, reader["MarkingCuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingGasPressure", MarkingGasPressure, reader["MarkingGasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingFrequency", MarkingFrequency, reader["MarkingFrequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingNozzleHeight", MarkingNozzleHeight, reader["MarkingNozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingPowerMin", MarkingPowerMin, reader["MarkingPowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingPowerMax", MarkingPowerMax, reader["MarkingPowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingDutyCycle", MarkingDutyCycle, reader["MarkingDutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingFocusHeight", MarkingFocusHeight, reader["MarkingFocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingLeadInFeed", MarkingLeadInFeed, reader["MarkingLeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@MarkingCompensation", MarkingCompensation, reader["MarkingCompensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolCuttingSpeed", PathCoolCuttingSpeed, reader["PathCoolCuttingSpeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolGasPressure", PathCoolGasPressure, reader["PathCoolGasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolFrequency", PathCoolFrequency, reader["PathCoolFrequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolNozzleHeight", PathCoolNozzleHeight, reader["PathCoolNozzleHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolPowerMin", PathCoolPowerMin, reader["PathCoolPowerMin"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolPowerMax", PathCoolPowerMax, reader["PathCoolPowerMax"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolDutyCycle", PathCoolDutyCycle, reader["PathCoolDutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolFocusHeight", PathCoolFocusHeight, reader["PathCoolFocusHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolLeadInFeed", PathCoolLeadInFeed, reader["PathCoolLeadInFeed"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PathCoolCompensation", PathCoolCompensation, reader["PathCoolCompensation"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Power", PiercingStage1Power, reader["PiercingStage1Power"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Frequency", PiercingStage1Frequency, reader["PiercingStage1Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1DutyCycle", PiercingStage1DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage1DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1PierceHeight", PiercingStage1PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage1PierceHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1Focus", PiercingStage1Focus, reader["PiercingStage1Focus"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1GasPressure", PiercingStage1GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage1GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1PierceTime", PiercingStage1PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage1PierceTime"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage1ProgressiveDelay"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Power", PiercingStage2Power, reader["PiercingStage2Power"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Frequency", PiercingStage2Frequency, reader["PiercingStage2Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2DutyCycle", PiercingStage2DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage2DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2PierceHeight", PiercingStage2PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage2PierceHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2Focus", PiercingStage2Focus, reader["PiercingStage2Focus"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2GasPressure", PiercingStage2GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage2GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2PierceTime", PiercingStage2PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage2PierceTime"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage2ProgressiveDelay"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Power", PiercingStage3Power, reader["PiercingStage3Power"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Frequency", PiercingStage3Frequency, reader["PiercingStage3Frequency"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3DutyCycle", PiercingStage3DutyCycle, reader["PiercingStage3DutyCycle"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3PierceHeight", PiercingStage3PierceHeight, reader["PiercingStage3PierceHeight"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3Focus", PiercingStage3Focus, reader["PiercingStage3Focus"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3GasPressure", PiercingStage3GasPressure, reader["PiercingStage3GasPressure"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3PierceTime", PiercingStage3PierceTime, reader["PiercingStage3PierceTime"]);
                            CompareAndSaveParameter("@PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay", PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay, reader["PiercingStage3ProgressiveDelay"]);

                            if (updatedValues.Count == 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("No changes found to be updated.");
                                return;
                            }

                            string updateQuery = $"UPDATE CuttingParameters SET " +
                            string.Join(", ", updatedValues.Select(kv => $"[{kv.Key}] = {GetFormValue(kv.Key)}")) +
                            $" WHERE (((CuttingParameters.Material) = [@Material]) AND ((CuttingParameters.Thickness) = [@Thickness]) AND ((CuttingParameters.Gas) = [@Gas]) AND ((CuttingParameters.PiercingType) = [@PiercingType]))";

                            Console.WriteLine("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);
                            logger.Log("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);
                                                            
                            try
                            {
                                using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, connection))
                                {
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", selectedMaterial);
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thickness", selectedThickness);
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gas", selectedGas);
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PiercingType", selectedPiercingType);

                                    foreach (var kvp in updatedValues)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
                                        logger.Log("Generated SQL update statement: " + updateQuery);
                                        logger.Log($"Parameter: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");

                                        OleDbParameter parameter;
                                        if (double.TryParse(kvp.Value.ToString(), out double doubleValue))
                                        {
                                            parameter = new OleDbParameter($"@{kvp.Key}", OleDbType.Double);
                                            parameter.Value = doubleValue;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            parameter = new OleDbParameter($"@{kvp.Key}", OleDbType.VarChar);
                                            parameter.Value = kvp.Value;
                                        }
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                                    }

                                    int rowsAffected = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    if (rowsAffected > 0)
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Parameters updated successfully.");
                                        logger.Log("Parameters updated successfully.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("No rows were updated. No changes found to be updated.");
                                        logger.Log("No rows were updated. No changes found to be updated.");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (OleDbException ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.Message);
                                logger.Log("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.Message);
                                logger.LogError("Failed to update parameters. Database Error: " + ex.ToString());
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.Message);
                                logger.Log("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.Message);
                                logger.LogError("Failed to update parameters. Error: " + ex.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.Message);
            logger.Log("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.Message);
            logger.LogError("An error occurred. Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```